# Google Sheets - Query Function - Search Using Named Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I'm making a sheet where I fill in my expenses for each month. I have a tab setup with several columns listed as 'Groceries' or 'Travel' (for example) that are my Named Ranges:

| Groceries | Travel |
| --- | --- |
| Tesco | Train |
| Asda | Parking |

I would like the formula to look down my list of initial data which would look like so:

| Expense | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Asda | £1 |
| Gifts | £2 |
| Tesco | £2 |
| Parking | £2 |

Then in each column it would show the relevant data, using the Named Ranges as the search key.

It would result in this:

| Groceries | Cost | Travel | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asda | £1 | Parking | £2 |
| Tesco | £2 |  |  |

So I would like my query to search for anything mentioned in the 'Groceries' Named Range and show the result.

For example the query I'm thinking of would look something like this:

| Groceries | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| =query($A$1:$B$5,"Select A where A = 'Groceries'),1) | =query($A$1:$B$5,"Select B where A = 'Groceries'),1) |

Is this possible? And is it possible using only formulas? I've never used scripts before.

I'm currently using a typical query formula =query($A$1:$C$5,"Select A where C = 'Groceries'",1) and manually giving each expense a category in a column C.

Basically I'm hoping to make my sheet more automated to save me manually typing in what category each expense is, and I wondered if this was possible without using an ungodly amount of IFS as that's the only other way I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## List by Groceries

It's simpler to use a FILTER function.

```
=FILTER(A:B, COUNTIF(Groceries, A:A))
```

Or, for Travel

```
=FILTER(A:B, COUNTIF(Travel, A:A))
```

[image: Spreadsheet showing data and Filter formula]

## SUM Groceries by Category

You could combine the FILTER and QUERY functions to group by grocery expense category.

##### FILTER in a QUERY

```
=QUERY(FILTER(A:B, COUNTIF(Groceries, A:A)),
   "Select Col1, SUM(Col2) group by Col1 
   label Col1 'Groceries', SUM(Col2) 'Total by Category'",0)
```

[image: Spreadsheet showing data and Filter in a Query formula]

##### QUERY in a FILTER

LET is needed here to reduce the amount of code duplication.

```
=LET(groc,QUERY(A:B, "Select A, SUM(B) Where 
   A is not Null Group by A Label A 'Groceries',
   SUM(B) 'Total by Category'",1),
  FILTER(groc, COUNTIF(Groceries, INDEX(groc,,1))))
```

[image: Spreadsheet showing data and Filter in a Query formula]

#### Function Support Links

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)

Comment: That's fantastic and works brilliantly, exactly what I was looking for! I'm still learning with formulas so I appreciate such a clear explanation! Thank you for this!